# From polar coordinates to Cartesian.

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

Please help me move from polar coordinates to Cartesian. $p=\sqrt{\cos(\pi + \phi})$. I tried to do that and made following steps, but I don't know if I'm right.

[image]

Comment: do you mean $$r=\sqrt{\cos(\pi+\phi)}$$?

Comment: See this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Converting_between_polar_and_Cartesian_coordinates $$r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\\\phi=\arctan\frac yx$$Use this (along with some trig identities probably) to convert

Comment: Dr. Sonnard Graubner, yes sir. John Doe, here I tried to do that and made some steps, but I don't know if I'm right. https://i.imgur.com/Y90Bibs.jpg Please tell me that.

Comment: Note that $\cos(\pi+\theta)=-\cos\theta=-x/r$. So using $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ we get $y=\pm\sqrt{(-x)^{2/3}-x^2}$. You need $x$ in the range -1 to 0. If you plot you get an oval.

Answer (score 0):

Let's limit $\theta$ to $[0,2\pi)$. Therefore$$r=\sqrt{-\cos\theta}\qquad,\qquad \dfrac{\pi}{2}\le\theta\le\dfrac{3\pi}{2}$$and we have$$\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)^3}=-x$$

Answer (score 0):

First try polar plot to grasp what is involved. The sign of quantity under radical sign is positive in quadrants 2 and 3.

Square root includes either sign even if not explicitly given. So all quadrants should be occupied. 
We have to square the equation to include both signs.

$$ r^2=-\cos \theta = \frac{-x}{r}$$

$$ r^3= -x$$

To include both signs square both sides.
$$ r^6= (x^2+y^2)^3 =x^2$$

So this is the cartesian form without change if $-x$ is plugged in place of $x$ or $-y$ is plugged in place of $y.$

There is symmetry with respect to both axes forming a 2 leaved bean shape.

[image]